# Handler.post() doesn't execute immediately

Tags: java, android, handler

I am doing a tic tac toe game using a Handler.post() to change the color of the ui square. But the handler always uses the opposite color, even though I am changing the color(player's turn) far later.

```
if (board[row][column] == 0) {
        if (isMyTurn == true) {
            board[row][column] = 1;
        } else {
            board[row][column] = 2;
        }
        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (isMyTurn == true) {
                    btn.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_light));
                } else {
                    btn.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_light));
                }
            }
        }); // end of Handler
} // end of makeMove()
```

Comment: I even added a loop inside the makeMove() with 100 millions loops just to take some time, but I am having the same problem. What could cause it?

Comment: why are you using a `Handler` at all?

Comment: to change the button(square) background color

Comment: so change it in the first `if`

Comment: first time I was using like that and then I had big problems with updating my UI. So people on forums were talking that for any UI change I should use Handler

Comment: so your code runs in a separate `Thread`? why?

Comment: Alright, I will try again. Last time when I had 3 in row it wasn't able to color the whole line, it automatically resets the board.

Answer (score 1):

Handler.post() add Runnable into queue so the O.S. doesn't execut it immediately. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#post%28java.lang.Runnable%29

Comment: but my ui depends on that Handler. What can I do to make it changes the color and then continue with the app?

Comment: create Handler from mainLooper like this Handler mainHandler = new Handler(context.getMainLooper()); , or use Activiti.runOnUIThread